# Installing Python's easy_install using ez_setup.py from behind a proxy server

Tags: python, proxy, easy-install

Is there a way to install Python's easy_install using ez_setup.py when on a corporate network that uses a proxy server?  Currently, I receive a connection timeout:

```
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\jsears\python\ez_setup.py", line 278, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\jsears\python\ez_setup.py", line 210, in main
    egg = download_setuptools(version, delay=0)
  File "C:\jsears\python\ez_setup.py", line 158, in download_setuptools
    src = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  File "C:\jsears\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\jsears\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\jsears\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\jsears\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\jsears\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1207, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\jsears\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1177, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, you can simply set an environment variable:

> export http_proxy=http://<user>:<password>@<proxy_host_name>:<port>

For example:

> export http_proxy=http://admin:password@proxy.example.com:80

Answer (score 15):

On Windows 7, with PowerShell, the proxy settings above are ignored, and the tool won't work. But I found the solution.

I modified the routine download_file_powershell by adding

```
[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials;
```

inside the scriptlet used to download via the WebClient class. Here is the complete download_file_powershell function now:

```
def download_file_powershell(url, target):
"""
Download the file at url to target using Powershell (which will validate
trust). Raise an exception if the command cannot complete.
"""
target = os.path.abspath(target)
cmd = [
    'powershell',
    '-Command',
    "[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials;  (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile(%(url)r, %(target)r)" % vars(),
]
subprocess.check_call(cmd)
```

Comment: Setuptools 3.6 integrates this technique. Can you confirm the technique works on all versions of Powershell and even when proxy credentials are unneeded?

Comment: Well, I use PowerShell quite rarely, so I cannot confirm that, sorry.

Comment: @valir can you please tell us where should I make the edit? Is it inside the ez_install.py or in some other python module? or somewhere else?

Answer (score 7):

If you already have a http_proxy/https_proxy environment variable set you can just tell ez_setup.py to not use PowerShell. PowerShell does not use HTTP_PROXY/HTTPS_PROXY environment variables. Follow the first section in this response.

For people who might not know how to set environment variables, see sections 2+.

**Stop ez_setup.py from using PowerShell**

Go into the ez_install.py and find the following section:

```
def has_powershell():
    if platform.system() != 'Windows':
        return False
    cmd = ['powershell', '-Command', 'echo test']
    devnull = open(os.path.devnull, 'wb')
    try:
        try:
            subprocess.check_call(cmd, stdout=devnull, stderr=devnull)
        except:
            return False
    finally:
        devnull.close()
    return True
```

and change it to be

```
def has_powershell():
     return False
```

ez_install.py will the use your environment HTTP_PROXY/HTTPS_PROXY which can be set from the command line or through the control panel.

**Temporary Command Line:**

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com
set HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.example.com
```

*Note:* if you do this you must run 'python ez_setup.py' in the same command window you ran these commands in.

**Permanent Command Line (User Only):**

```
setx HTTP_PROXY "http://proxy.example.com"
setx HTTPS_PROXY "https://proxy.example.com"
```

**Permanent Command Line (Machine aka All Users):**

```
setx HTTP_PROXY "http://proxy.example.com" /M
setx HTTPS_PROXY "https://proxy.example.com" /M
```

**Permanent via Control Panel:**

1. Start -> Control Panel -> User Accounts
2. On left panel, click "Change my environment variables"
3. Click "New.." in "User variables" or "System Variables" (depending on what you want)
4. Set Variable name: HTTP_PROXY and Variable value: http:/proxy.example.com
5. Click "New.." in "User variables" or "System Variables" (depending on what you want)
6. Set Variable name: HTTPS_PROXY and Variable value: https:/proxy.example.com
7. Click 'Ok'

Answer (score 4):

you can also set in your code:

```
import urllib2

proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http':'http://username:password@proxy_host:port'})
auth = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy, auth, urllib2.HTTPHandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

Comment: Yes, I could modify ez_setup.py, but that script is provided by PEAK, so and I didn't want to hack about in their script.  Thanks for the proposal, as that will help with other scripts I write.

Comment: This worked for me on windows, while setting the environment variables didn't. I added the above lines at the beginning of the ez_setup script, and also included the same proxy for https (just another entry in the dictionary with https instead of http).

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem and this is the solution I have found. I'll admit is not ideal, but it is only way I found around this issue on Windows.

1. Download. ez_setup.py.
2. Edit the following line to show you where the file expect to download the zipped up package to:

print saveto

```
def download_setuptools(version=DEFAULT_VERSION, download_base=DEFAULT_URL,
                        to_dir=os.curdir, delay=15,
                        downloader_factory=get_best_downloader):
# making sure we use the absolute path
to_dir = os.path.abspath(to_dir)
tgz_name = "setuptools-%s.tar.gz" % version
url = download_base + tgz_name
saveto = os.path.join(to_dir, tgz_name)
print saveto
if not os.path.exists(saveto):  # Avoid repeated downloads
    log.warn("Downloading %s", url)
    downloader = downloader_factory()
    downloader(url, saveto)
return os.path.realpath(saveto)
```

This provides the following output when you execute the script in my case: "C:\Python27>python.exe ez_setup.py"

Output:

C:\Python27\setuptools-1.4.2.tar.gz
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-1.4.2.tar.gz
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required."
At line:1 char:47
+ (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile <<<< ('https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-1.4.2.tar.gz', 'C:\Python27\setuptools-1.4.2.tar.gz')
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

1. Download the pack from the https link above and put it in location it expects in my case "C:\Python27\"

This file being placed in the location triggers this logic statement:

```
if not os.path.exists(saveto):  # Avoid repeated downloads
    log.warn("Downloading %s", url)
    downloader = downloader_factory()
    downloader(url, saveto)
return os.path.realpath(saveto)
```

As if by magic, the package will be installed.