# Can't install setuptools (python)

Tags: python, setuptools

I have Windows 7 (64-bit) operating system. I have installed python. I want to install setuptools (for python).
In their website (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) it is written: "Download ez_setup.py and run it;"
I download that file, save it to my hard drive. Then when I click (right mouse button) and select "Open with"-> "python", a black console screen appears for a second, then disappears. And that's all.
What is wrong and how can I install that software?

Comment: hold shift then right-click in the explorer window to then select "Open Console window here".  Then run the command from the console to see the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open a command prompt (Start menu -> cmd.exe)
2. Navigate to the directory where ez_setup.py is saved, e.g.:

   ```
   cd C:\Users\You\Downloads
   ```
3. Run it (C:\Python27\ should already be on your %PATH%; if it's not, add it -- see below):

   ```
   python ez_setup.py
   ```
4. Read the output. If it worked, you should be able to install packages like so:

   ```
   C:\Python27\Scripts\easy_install jinja2
   ```
5. Add the path to `easy_install` to your %PATH% so that you can use it easily from any directory:

   1. Control Panel -> System -> Advanced system settings
   2. Click the `Environment variables...` button
   3. Edit PATH and append `;C:\Python27\Scripts\` to the end (substitute your Python version)
   4. Click OK. Note that changes to the PATH are only reflected in command prompts opened *after* the change took place.

If something goes wrong, the command prompt will remain open after the program finishes, so you'll be able to read the error and use it to resolve the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! Only after your complete explanation I understood how all these things work!

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do this but I'm behind a proxy server so this 'python ez_setup.py' is failing because as I saw ez_setup is using powershell to download the file... is there any way to do this behind a proxy server?

Comment: @Geykel: [Apparently there is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18790045/21475)! Never tried it myself, though.