# How to use easy_install behind a http proxy on windows?

Tags: python, proxy, easy-install

When I use the command:

`easy_install spotter`

to install the `spotter` package, I got the following error message

```
Searching for spotter
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/spotter/
Download error on http://pypi.python.org/simple/spotter/: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo      failed -- Some packages may not be found!
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/spotter/
Download error on http://pypi.python.org/simple/spotter/: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'spotter' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on http://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for spotter
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('spotter')
```

The two environment variables: `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` seem not to work?

[Installing Python's easy_install using ez_setup.py from behind a proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733375/installing-pythons-easy-install-using-ez-setup-py-from-behind-a-proxy-server)

Comment: Setting `http_proxy` works for me. What exactly are you doing?

Answer (score 15):

Did you try the following:

```
$ export http_proxy=http://username:password@some.proxy.com:portnumber
$ export https_proxy=https://username:password@some.proxy.com:portnumber
```

And then

```
$ sudo -E easy_install spotter
```

I had a problem similar to yours (I'm behind a very restrictive firewall+proxy combination) and the above set of commands and combinations worked for me (in a GNU/Linux environment, particularly Ubuntu).

Comment: This worked for me. I was missing the `-E` on `sudo`.

Answer (score 4):

You have to put your proxy configuration in Internet Explorer and restart your terminal.

[proxy configuration in Internet Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQDgk.png)

Answer (score 4):

From the Windows command prompt, first set the two environment variables:

```
c:\> set http_proxy=<user>:<password>@<proxy_ip_address>:<port>
c:\> set https_proxy=<user>:<password>@<proxy_ip_address>:<port>
```

Then, I was able to run (in the same terminal):

```
easy_install spotter
```