# Python Error When Installing ez_setup.py "could not create SSL/TLS secure channel"

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl

**Python version:** 2.7.13

**OS:** Windows Server 2012

I'm following this [tutorial](http://newcoder.io/begin/setup-your-machine/#windows) to set up Python environment

When I attempt to execute

```
python ~\Desktop\ez_setup.py
```

I get

```
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure
channel."
At line:1 char:106
+ [System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCac ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
```

I tried enabling SSL and TLS based on this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/a6f6fa60-03fb-49f6-b356-de4aa7633738/how-to-disable-tls-and-enable-ssl30-on-iis?forum=winserverNIS) and restarting the Server, but no luck

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: It doesn't help the SSL issue but you might be able to use the --insecure flag per https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/106

Comment: @TarunLalwani Yes, I am behind proxy at office

Comment: @Rhonda, see if this is of any help https://stackoverflow.com/a/18790045/2830850

Comment: @BrendanSamek This works. If you put it in answer, I will mark it as accepted solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround you can use the --insecure flag, although it doesn't fix the SSL error.

Source: [Github Setuptools Issues](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/106)

Answer (score 2):

If you're installing pip via `get-pip.py`, is it even necessary to install `ez_setup` first? It seems like that tutorial might be out of date.